# Trouble getting JQuery AJAX's success event to show a thank you page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code and, if everything is okay, the result should be a thank you page.
Here is the code:

```
<a class="large red button round" onclick="$.ajax({ type: 'POST', data:$('#newsletter').serialize(), url: 'http://www.stress-free-life.co.il/lists/?p=subscribe&    amp;id=1', success: function (msg) { openWin(); $('#Name').val(''); $('#email').val(''); }, failure: function (msg) { alert('Sorry, we were unable to process your subscription.'); } }); return false;" href="javascript; return false;">לחץ כאן</a>
```

I have tried several options but can't get the thank you page to display.

Comment: You should *reallllllllly* move that `onclick` into it's own function. (readability wise, an inline AJAX call is....a pain in the ass to work with)

Comment: eewww must you use inline js?

Comment: That inline code hurts my eyeballs!!

Comment: Ummm ya.... You're using `jquery`, and you're using it's nice `ajax` functionality.  But you're still calling it obtrusively!  >.<  Don't use onclick handlers!  That's very 1995.

Comment: so how could i fixe it?

Answer (score 1):

Um... let's clean this up, onclick handlers are *really* hard to read and are generally considered bad practice

Your HTML:

```
<a class="large red button round my-button" href='#'>לחץ כאן</a>
```

And in a separate JS file you should have:

```
$(function(){
  $('.my-button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: $('#newsletter').serialize(),
      url: 'http://www.stress-free-life.co.il/lists/?p=subscribe&id=1',
      success: function(msg){
        window.location = "/my-thank-you-page.html";
        //openWin();  // No idea what this function is...
        //$('#Name').val('');
        //$('#email').val('');
      },
      failure: function(msg){
        alert('Sorry, we were unable to process your subscription.');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yours is much better :)

Comment: Are there javascript errors in your JS console?  What behavior are you seeing?  Did you put your thank you URL in the window.location area?

Comment: i put my thank you URL in the window.location area
it simply pressed and do but still left in the same page

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to look at the network tab.  When you click the link, does it show a request being fired off to `stress-free-life.co.il/lists`, and then does it show it returning with a `200` response?  Also, where did you put the javascript code?  If it's in an external JS file, are you linking to it from your HTML page?

Comment: the stress-free-life.co.il/lists is ok it do what it has to do and in the networl tab in the status it show canceled the javascript code is in the same page between <script> <script/> tags

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this...

```
<a id="ajaxpost" class="large red button round" href="javascript:void(0)">לחץ כאן<a>


<script>

$("#ajaxpost").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#newsletter').serialize(),
        url: 'http://www.stress-free-life.co.il/lists/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1',
        success: function (msg) {
            openWin();

            $('#Name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            window.location = "url of thank-you page";
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            alert('Sorry, we were unable to process your subscription.');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```